# Xamarin.Forms adding Effect to all Entries in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the FormsCommunityToolkit NuGet Package to make it so all of my Entries in my Xamarin.Forms app select all of their text when a user clicks on them.  The example on [their GitHub](https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/Effects/blob/dev/samples/Effects.SampleApp/Views/EntryPage.xaml) for using this effect on an `Entry` in XAML is this:

```
<Entry Placeholder="focus this entry." VerticalOptions="Start" Text = "FOCUS THIS!">
  <Entry.Effects>
    <effects:SelectAllTextEntryEffect />
  </Entry.Effects>
</Entry>
```

This works if you put it on each individual `Entry` in your code, but I have a lot of Entries and would like to set it as the default in my `App.xaml` folder.  I tried this:

```
<Style TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="Text"/> <!--Defaults to capitalize first word-->
    <Setter Property="Effects" Value="effects:SelectAllTextEntryEffect" />
</Style>
```

This method works for setting the default `Keyboard` for all entries, but setting the Effects in this way crashes the app with this error:

```
Can't resolve EffectsProperty on Entry
```

Does anybody know a way of doing this so I don't need to add the code to all of my Entries?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I need to add an effect to every entry on my app to remove the Underline on Android. But I can't style it because it fails with "Can't resolve EffectsProperty on Entry" Have you managed to solve it? I can't create a custom entry control because I do use SfTextInput from Syncfusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create your own `Entry` which has the Effect?

So create an inheritance of the `Entry`, I will call it `EffectEntry`. You can do this by creating a new XAML file and put the contents of your `Entry` in there. Yo probably want to remove the properties like `PlaceHolder` and `Text`, but if there is a property that you would like on all your entries as a default, apply them here.

```
<Entry>
  <Entry.Effects>
    <effects:SelectAllTextEntryEffect />
  </Entry.Effects>
</Entry>
```

Go to the code-behind and make sure your `EffectEntry` inherits the `Entry`.

```
namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public partial class EffectEntry : Button
    {
        public EffectEntry ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the rest of your app you can just use your `Entry` with the effect already added like this:

```
<controls:EffectEntry Placeholder="focus this entry." VerticalOptions="Start" Text = "FOCUS THIS!" />
```

Note that `controls` is a namespace that you have to add yourself. The name could be different to. In context with a whole page it could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls" 
    x:Class="MyApp.MyAppPage">

    <controls:EffectEntry Placeholder="focus this entry." VerticalOptions="Start" Text = "FOCUS THIS!" />
</ContentPage>
```

Notice how there are multiple `xmlns` (XML Namespace) entries at the top. I have added the controls one, you could also name it any other way you like. When you look at the code-behind of our `EffectEntry`, you will see that the namespace there and here match. This way the app knows where to find the control. If you decide that you want to move the controls to their own assembly, you can also define this like `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls;assembly=MyProject.Example"`.

Comment: I set this all up and got the following error:  "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 96:121. StaticResource not found for key selectAllEntry". I set the namespace in my page using the entry for local, controls, and effects.  There is also the namespace for effects in my EffectEntry Xaml.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with implementing the entry this way. It sounds like you are trying to use a static resource (find `{StaticResource selectAllEntry}` in your XAML) which cannot be found. Make sure you have the resource dictionary included in the page where you are using the `selectAllEntry` resource

Comment: Are there docs for this?  I believe it is the correct answer, I'm just confused exactly how to implement it.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. But it seems to me the error lies somewhere else. Maybe in your `App.xaml` where you still have some kind of style defined. Look for the `selectAllEntry` key in your code. Since that is indicated by the error, something seems wrong there.